# Cannot access json file with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, get, xmlhttprequest

I want to read the json content of this page : `http://89.92.40.250:8010/dreamteam/interface/get_event_detail.php?id=397` with javascript.

So i began this script :

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://89.92.40.250:8010/dreamteam/interface/get_event_detail.php?id=397", true); 
    req.onreadystatechange = monCode;   
    req.send(null);      

    function monCode() { 
        if (req.readyState == 4) { 
            var doc = eval('(' + req.responseText + ')');
            alert(req.responseText);
        }
    }
```

when I want to show the content I use alert(req.responseText); and I don't see the content. Plus I have a syntax error with Firebug : syntax error : var doc = eval('(' + req.responseText + ')');

Impossible with JSONP.

Can we extract the content of the page, then convert it to JSON format then parse it ??

Comment: Try to show through alert req.responseText and see what you receive there.

Comment: Perhaps you are doing an AJAX request to a different server that the one the page is displayed from? Cross-domain requests are not allowed by browsers, you should use JSONP instead.

Comment: @Sergey : with the  alert req.responseText I see nothing

Comment: @Pedro : Yes I'm working in localhost faraway 89.92.40.250 Can you explain how to do with JSONP

Comment: what is the URL that your are currently seeing in your browser and do you see any alerts in the console?

Comment: I work in localhost (127.0.0.1) in my computer

Comment: the problem is about cross-domain restrictions as mentioned, also that is not a valid json response, there is no value for `latitude` and `longitude`, can you share a valid url?

Comment: ok I updated my post and change the id from 106 to 397.

Comment: Can we extract the content of the page, then convert it to JSON format then parse it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't create a your own proxy, you should use YQL to avoid cross domain problem.

here is an example url for `id=397`,

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2F89.92.40.250%3A8010%2Fdreamteam%2Finterface%2Fget_event_detail.php%3Fid%3D397'&format=json&diagnostics=true
```

and you can set id dynamically like this,

```
var id = 397;
var baseurl = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
var q = "select * from json where url = 'http://89.92.40.250:8010/dreamteam/interface/get_event_detail.php?id="+id+"'";  
var url = baseurl + encodeURI(q) + "&format=json&diagnostics=true";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.onreadystatechange = monCode;
req.send(null);

function monCode() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText).query.results;
        console.log(data);
        //console.log(data.event);
        alert(data.event.title);
    }
}​
```

And [here is a jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y2fa6/1/)

[Usage Limits for YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

- Per application limit (identified by your Access Key): 100,000 calls per day
- Per IP limits: /v1/public/*: 2,000 calls per hour; /v1/yql/*: 20,000 calls per hour

Comment: Is there a rate limit for YQL request ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to cross-domain restrictions; your page should be hosted on the same host.

You could invest in the following alternatives:

- use JSONP (probably won't work in your case)
- use server-side script on the same host that will pull the file contents (like a proxy)
- look at ways to configure cross domain acces control: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control (not likely an option for you either)

Comment: Can we extract the content of the page, then convert it to JSON format then parse it ??

Comment: I'm going to make a guess here and say that you don't own the page that you're trying to load. In that case, you're left with creating a server side script that loads the file contents. Sorry to disappoint you, but cross domain policies just work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a request from 127.0.0.1 to 89.92.40.250:8010 it is going to be a cross domain request, it is a cross domain request even if you access a different port on the same machine like 127.0.0.1:8080.

If you have control over the content rendered by 89.92.40.250:8010 you could use `jsonp` to get around the cross domain restriction but it needs some changes on the backend or you can use a functionality provided by http://jsonp.jit.su/ which basically contacts the server on your behalf, creates a `jsonp` response which you can handle.

Comment: Can we extract the content of the page, then convert it to JSON format then parse it ??

Answer (score 0):

As I said above in my comment, you cannot do cross-domain AJAX requests. Browsers normally forbid this.

If you really want to do a cross-domain request, there are several options, one being proxying (configure your local webserver to send the request to the remote server) and the other [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)).

JSONP basically consists in adding an extra `script` tag to your HTML document whilst using the request URL as `src`. This allows you to bypass cross-domain security control, as you can always include JS resources from other sites. However, the remote server must know that it has to apply a prefix to the request (i.e. `read_data({ /* JSON response */});`, otherwise the returned information won't be processed.

**UPDATE**

jQuery, for instance, can handle JSONP transparently, as if it were a normal AJAX request:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

i.e.:

```
$.ajax({url:'http://your/request/url/',
        jsonp: 'your_desired_prefix',
        success: function(result) {
          /* result should hold you JSON data */
        });
```

Comment: Can we extract the content of the page, then convert it to JSON format then parse it ??

Comment: No need to parse anything, just return the JSON, prefixed by the function call, and that should work OK. There are also client-side tools that can do this transparently - I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried this `$.ajax({url:'http://89.92.40.250:8010/dreamteam/interface/get_event_detail.php?id=397',
     jsonp: '',
     success: function(result) {
       alert(result);
     }});` There is no error but the alert doesn't show anything

Comment: What is 'your_desired_prefix' ?

Comment: you can't make JSONP request for this url, it's not support JSONP callback.

Comment: obviously, the request handler needs to be modified in order to accept JSONP prefixes.