# Cannot access json page with JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I use JSONP to access to a json page (via jQuery). I have  an html button

`<input type="button" value="Récupérer les données" onclick="getInfo();" />`

my Code

```
function getInfo() {
                $.ajax({
                    dataType:'jsonp',
                    url: 'http://89.92.40.250:8010/dreamteam/interface/get_event_detail.php?id=106',
                    data: { param:'event' },
                    success:function(response) {
                    alert("Réponse : "+ response.data);
                    }
                });
            };
```

the alert doesn't work...

Comment: first of all, is it actually JSONP you are receiving?

Comment: It's JSON, you can try : http://89.92.40.250:8010/dreamteam/interface/get_event_detail.php?id=106

Comment: i think ajax do not allow to get data from external url

Comment: The server doesn't seem to support JSONP

Comment: JSONP is not magic. Your remote server must explicitly support it.

Comment: Ok and what to do if the support doesn't support it. How to parse the json ?

Comment: You can't.  You need server-side code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot acces json file with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571478/cannot-acces-json-file-with-javascript)

Comment: But I see the json in my browser... I just want to parse it. Why it's not simple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That server doesn't support JSONP, at least not with the standard `callback` parameter construct.

Consider using a server-side solution to this problem.

**BTW**

Original question: [Cannot access json file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571478/cannot-acces-json-file-with-javascript)

Hello again, at SO you can edit your existing questions or engage with those who answer; you don't have to ask another question with basically the same problem.

Comment: Ok and what to do if the support doesn't support it. How to parse the json ?

Comment: For me it's 2 problems :
- doesn't work with JSONP
- how to parse a json page

Comment: @CHABLIYA No, you have one problem; you want to parse a JSON external file. Trying JSONP was one of the suggestions, so if that didn't work you should add a comment to the original answer instead of creating another question. No offense, I hope you understand.

Comment: Ok. How to delete the second topic ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to delete a question. Maybe you need more reputation for that.

Answer (score 1):

As a safety precaution you cannot make cross origin requests see [**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) as alternative you can make a server side proxy, have that proxy call the web service you intend to call and return you the response in whatever format you like, be it `xml` or `json`. As @SLaks mentioned in the comments you cannot consume `jsonp` unless the remote server approves of it.